# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView, recyclerView and SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android

I am working on android project

and now in my layout I have this error:

```
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v7.widget.CardView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

I tried many selotions in stackOverFlow and other, but I faild to solove my problem.

Also I have this FATAL error in the logcat:

> 2019-08-18 15:36:08.069 13405-13405/com.example.souqsenae E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.souqsenae, PID: 13405
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.souqsenae/com.example.souqsenae.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3364)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3548)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2155)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7539)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.CardView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.souqsenae-0cR1gMxdpqx9a6GmZb9xEw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.souqsenae-0cR1gMxdpqx9a6GmZb9xEw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]

### This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "70dp"
        android:elevation="24dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_action_bar"
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">
          <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_my_location_black_24dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
            android:drawableTint="@color/gray"
            android:hint="@string/search"
            android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke_gray"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/white_action_bar"
                android:layout_below="@id/first"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:id="@+id/taskBar">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/new_"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.45"
                    android:id="@+id/btnAvailable"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/small_divider"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/used"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_weight="0.45"
                    android:id="@+id/btnMyJob"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:elevation="24dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:id="@+id/layout_task_item"
                android:layout_below="@id/taskBar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view2"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
                    android:innerRadius="0dp"
                    android:shape="rectangle"
                    android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"

                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
                    </ImageView>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            >
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/app_name"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                                android:id="@+id/tvClientName"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/app_name"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                                android:id="@+id/tvTaskType"
                                android:textStyle="italic"/>
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/app_name"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:id="@+id/tvTaskDesc"
                                android:textStyle="italic"
                                android:visibility="gone"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_task_item"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/listContainer"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/no_data"
                    android:text="@string/no_data"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
                <ProgressBar
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/progress"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/no_data"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>




                <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/listTasks"
                        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
                </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "50dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/end"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/white_menu_bar"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
           <Button
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="0.2"
               android:background="@android:color/transparent"
               android:text="@string/home"
               android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="@string/my_order"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="@string/notifications"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>



        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### and this is my style file:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

> I add 'Base' word as an seotion I found it but also not work..

### The dependencies:

```
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'

implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.0'
```

any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Firstly**

By now you should be aware that with the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) which is part of [Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack)

Support Library version 28.0.0 is the last feature release under the `android.support packaging`, and developers are encouraged to migrate to AndroidX. There is nothing like `...support:v29.0.0` so I doubt if your project will build successfully.

**Secondly**

You cannot mix both `support` and `androidx` libraries together in the same project, there will surely be conflicts unless you're using `Jetpack` tool. Migrate your support libraries to androidx using this [Artifacts mapping](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings)

*And Finally**

References in an Androidx layout file should all be androidx artifacts and not otherwise.

Hence tag like this:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent
```

Should be:

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

instead of

```
android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using both support library and androidx library. Either use support library or use androidx

Use androidx library :

```
 androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

 androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

 androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

instead of

```
android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

And in grade file add dependencies for androidx card view, swipe refresh layout and recyclerview.

Also, see Migrating to AndroidX
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate